# Visual Studio Deployment Package Change File Security

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, file-security, programdata

I have a Deployment Package created in Visual Studio that includes an Access (MDB) file that gets deployed to C:\ProgramData\AppName folder. When I try to use the installed application, I observe that it can read from the MDB but cannot write to it.

In the MDB file properties > Security tab, the Users permissions are set to Read but not Write. This may be the reason for this issue. Who can I fix this issue so that the security is set to Full Control for Users?